# cordova facebook plugin crash

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, crash, facebook-login

I'm testing Cordova Facebook plugin like [phonegap-facebook-plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin) but I have problems with some Android devices with Facebook Login.

With these devices, when I try to login via Facebook the app crashes, disappears going into the background. Debugging I discovered that this happens after `onDestroy` method is called. Devices that run on small memory condition underline this problem.
Android framework calls `onDestroy` before Facebook login is finished. Facebook login takes long time and uses its own thread but the activity main thread is killed by Android.

Did anybody notice this problem ?

I discovered that this problem is related to "Do not keep activity" of debug developer options.

Comment: Can you please provide code snippet ?

Comment: Simple code provided by plugin

Comment: You can test this plugin https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin or this https://github.com/ccsoft/cordova-facebook. The problem is the same